# Javascript count the number of checked boxes in a TABLE row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 3 checkboxes in each row. I want to make sure that at least 2 of them are checked at a given time.

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Looking for something like this in Javascript-

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked').length < 2) {
        alert('You must check at least 2 checkboxes');
    }
});
```

Should be a simple syntactical thing but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `$('#mytable [type=checkbox]:checked').length` should work instead of a `.each()`. `[type=checkbox]` can be many thing depending on your HTML.

Comment: @kev are you looking for it in plain js or in jquery? either way, this is a low quality question and a likely duplicate.

Comment: @r3wt the other answers are counting checkboxes in a document. the syntax for my answer was a bit different. jeez, you guys make it really hard for newbies to learn a new language, don't you?

Comment: @kev the same answer applies to your situation, you can query off of any node, whether its the `document` or some arbirtrary domNode of your choice. in your case the root would be `document.getElementById('mytable')` or `document.querySelector('#mytable')`. then you just change a `getElementsByTagName('input')` off of that node.

Comment: so you mean `document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `filter(':checked')` instead of `is()`

```js
$('#mytable').find('tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').length < 2) {
        alert('You must check at least 2 checkboxes');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As mentioned in the comments you can just select checked inputs in the first place with `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` without filtering.

Comment: how is this a JS solution?

Comment: It's not pure JavaScipt. OP has used jQuery in his code, so I have used it too.